# asp-route tag helper doesn't generate url correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am using the following code in a <button> tag in a partial Razor View.  It generates a 'formaction' attribute in the button element.  However, it doesn't generate querystring for asp-route-searchCriteria, asp-route-orderBy, and asp-route-pageNumber.

Here is the action signature:

```js
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string stage, string patientID, string patientName, int episodeID, string searchCriteria, int pageNumber, string orderBy)
```

```html
    @if (stage != "PatientList")
    {
      <div class="mdc-touch-target-wrapper">
        <button id="@($"{stage}_{Model.PatientID}")"
                class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-button--touch @(actionBtnCssClass) rehabAction"
                data-stage="@(stage)"
                asp-controller="question" asp-action="Edit" 
                asp-route-stage="@(aspRouteParamStage)" 
                asp-route-patientID="@(Model.PatientID)" 
                asp-route-patientName="@(Model.PatientName)" 
                asp-route-episodeID="@(Model.EpisodeID)" 
                asp-route-searchCriteria="@(Model.SearchCriteria)"
                asp-route-orderBy="@(Model.OrderBy)"
                asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageNumber)"> 
          <span class="mdc-button__ripple"></span>
          <span class="mdc-button__label">@textNode</span>
          <div class="mdc-button__touch"></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    }
    else
    {
      if (Model.HostContainer == "Question")
      {
        <div class="mdc-touch-target-wrapper">
          <button id="patient"
                  class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-button--touch @(actionBtnCssClass) rehabAction"
                  data-stage="@(stage)"
                  asp-controller="patient" asp-action="Index" 
                  asp-route-searchCriteria="@(Model.SearchCriteria)"
                  asp-route-orderBy="@(Model.OrderBy)"
                  asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageNumber)">
            <span class="mdc-button__ripple"></span>
            <span class="mdc-button__label">Patients</span>
            <span class="mdc-button__touch"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      }
    }
```

One of the generated button element is like below

```html
<button id="Followup_9999" class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-button--touch actionBtnFollowup rehabAction" data-stage="Followup" 
formaction="/question/Edit?
stage=Followup&amp;patientID=omitted
&amp;patientName=omitted%20W&amp;episodeID=-1"> 
          <span class="mdc-button__ripple"></span>
          <span class="mdc-button__label">Followup</span>
          <div class="mdc-button__touch"></div>
        </button>
```

Comment: Can you share your Model data?It seems your formaction format is not right,it should be `&` between `stage=xxx` and `patientID=xxx`.

Comment: Typo? `asp-route-pageNaumber != asp-route-pageNumber`. Can you post the method signature of `QuestionController.Edit` ?

Comment: it seems that the empty values for the asp-route-xxx are not included in the generated 'formaction'. I was expecting it to generate xxx=""&yyy=""&zzz="".

Comment: If the values are empty,they will not be added into the url,it is by design.